# Multiline UILabel in uicollectionViewCell wrong height

Tags: swift, layout, uilabel, cell, uicollectionviewcell

I insert a multi-line label inside the cell, the cell is not sized correctly. When I use it as a single line label, it's fine, but when I use multiple, the height is wrong. Even though I used SizeToFit() I couldn't find the solution. I need to use Cell i automatic size. When I scroll, the problem is fixed, but there is wrong on the first boot.
Any suggestions what can I do?

[wrong cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ElRu.png)
[state after scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahj6c.png)

Comment: add label inside stack view it will automatically set cell height as per the label content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved, I needed to add a contentView inside the cell and set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`.
Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```swift
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
```

also, make sure to align all UILabel edges to cell.contentView.